# Show div if radio button is checked, base the selector off of the input value contains

Tags: jquery

I would like to show .button if the first radio button "I understand and agree . . ." is selected. Because this is built using software, I need the selector to be based off of the radio button's value contains. .button is hidden by default. Please Help!

```
<style type="text/css">
 .button {
 display: none;
 }
 </style>

 <form>
 <input type="radio"  value="I understand and agree to the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest (you must agree to proceed with registration)" name="consent"><label>I understand and agree to the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest (you must agree to proceed with registration)</label>
 <br /> <input type="radio" name="consent" value="No, I do not agree with the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest"><label>No, I do not understand</label>
 </form>
 <div class="button">button</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/qob78w5r/3/

Comment: Firstly, i recommend a button to be visible no matter on selection but rather you can change the property "disabled" on it. The solution to achive this only by selector I don't think it's possible. You'd rather need a javascript code that would enable/disable button on radio value change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
   if($("input[value='I understand and agree to the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest (you must agree to proceed with registration)']").is(":checked")) {
       $(".button").show();
   } else {
       $(".button").hide();
   }
});
```

Basically, you attach an event to all the radio buttons. Every time, the value of one of them changes, you verify if the first one is checked. If it is, you show the div, otherwise you hide it.

Comment: I need the selector to be based on the text in the value instead of first, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, give me a second.

Comment: Edited to search the element by its value.

Answer (score 2):

If you move your button into the form, then you can just use CSS:

```css
.button {
  display: none;
}
input[name=consent]:checked~input[name=consent]~.button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" value="I understand and agree to the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest (you must agree to proceed with registration)" name="consent">
  <label>I understand and agree to the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest (you must agree to proceed with registration)</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="consent" value="No, I do not agree with the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest">
  <label>No, I do not understand</label>
  <div class="button">button</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I cannot directly edit HTML, the code is out created by the software.

Comment: That's pretty odd software, assuming the button is meant to submit the form, yet, it is outside the form itself.

Comment: Yes, I cannot do anything about how the software outputs the code, this is just how it works. That is why I have to create crazy work arounds.

Answer (score 1):

[toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) the button's display based on if the checked input's value contains the words, "I understand".

You can also put the inputs *inside* the labels, which would allow you to click the text as well as the tiny radio button:

```js
$('input:radio').change(function() {
  $('.button').toggle(/I understand/.test(this.value));
});
```

```css
.button {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="radio"  value="I understand and agree to the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest (you must agree to proceed with registration)" name="consent">I understand and agree to the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest (you must agree to proceed with registration)</label>
   <br />
 <label>
   <input type="radio" name="consent" value="No, I do not agree with the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest">No, I do not understand</label>
</form>
    
<div class="button">button</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to use attribute instead of text comparison :

```
 <input type="radio" allow="true"  value="I understand and agree to the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest (you must agree to proceed with registration)" name="consent"><label>I understand and agree to the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest (you must agree to proceed with registration)</label>
 <br /> <input type="radio" allow="false" name="consent" value="No, I do not agree with the rules of the Turning Points Essay Contest"><label>No, I do not understand</label>
 </form>
 <div class="button">button</div>

$("input:radio").change(function()
{
   $(".button").toggle($(this).attr("allow"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wd1z0zmg/6/

Comment: Software outputs the code, I cannot directly edit the HTML. Due to the way the software outputs the code across the site I have to use a text comparison in order to prevent effecting other pages or steps.